# How to set the alignment of an panel

Tags: java, javafx

I have set a panel in SceneBuilder; this should always be in the middle of the window. How do I do this?

I tried to set the anchor pane constraints, because my panel is in an anchor pane; but then the size of my panel changes, and I don't really want that.

[Example what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbGpB.png)
For example, the black panel does not stay in the center. But it's not even necessarily about the panel, if I use a rectangle instead of the panel, it doesn't stay positioned in the middle either, I need a square exactly in the middle for design reasons.

Comment: How the root of the FXML file is aligned in whatever contains it is determined by setting on the thing that contains it, not on settings on the thing itself. If it’s used directly as the root of the scene, it will be resized to fill the entire scene (no matter what it’s preferred, minimum, or maximum sizes are). So in this case it is already “in the middle of the window”, albeit in a trivial sense (there is no space around it). You are probably asking the wrong question here. Create and post a [mre] demonstrating the problem. Why are you using an `AnchorPane`?

Comment: `StackPane` is a convenient alternative, as it "defaults to `Pos.CENTER`."

Comment: In the middle of the window… by itself?  Nothing else is in that window?

Comment: Thank you, i am using an anchorpane because i have several elements, for example, two pieces must always be at a certain corner and must not move, so two panels and that works best if i have an anchorpane before and then put the two panels at the two corners.

Comment: But that contradicts what is in your picture. The black panel is not in a corner.

Comment: Yes, putting elements in the corner is not a problem for me either. That is possible. I just can't put one perfectly in the center as it should be demonstrated with the black bar. IF I put an element in the center and then resize the window, it is no longer in the center. The thing about the elements in the corners was related to your question about why I use an anchor panel. I use it because in addition to the element in the center, I also place elements in the corners.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using AnchorPane is not recommended.  As you have discovered, setting exact locations and sizes does not work when the window’s size changes.

[Layouts](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html) are designed to address this problem.  As trashgod pointed out, a [StackPane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) will center its contents by default.  [BorderPane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html)s can be used to position nodes at the corners:

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CornersAndCenterDemo
extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Rectangle centerRect = createRectangle();

        Rectangle topLeftRect = createRectangle();
        Rectangle topRightRect = createRectangle();

        Rectangle bottomLeftRect = createRectangle();
        Rectangle bottomRightRect = createRectangle();

        StackPane centerPane = new StackPane(centerRect);

        BorderPane topPane = new BorderPane();
        topPane.setLeft(topLeftRect);
        topPane.setRight(topRightRect);

        BorderPane bottomPane = new BorderPane();
        bottomPane.setLeft(bottomLeftRect);
        bottomPane.setRight(bottomRightRect);

        BorderPane cornersAndCenter = new BorderPane();
        cornersAndCenter.setCenter(centerPane);
        cornersAndCenter.setTop(topPane);
        cornersAndCenter.setBottom(bottomPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(cornersAndCenter, 800, 800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Corners and Center");
        stage.show();
    }

    private Rectangle createRectangle() {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 150, 150);
        rect.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        return rect;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(CornersAndCenterDemo.class, args);
    }
}
```

If you prefer to use SceneBuilder, the FXML would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="CornersAndCenterController">
    <center>
        <StackPane>
            <children>
                <Rectangle style="-fx-fill: black;" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150"/>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
    </center>
    <top>
        <BorderPane>
            <left>
                <Rectangle style="-fx-fill: black;" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150"/>
            </left>
            <right>
                <Rectangle style="-fx-fill: black;" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150"/>
            </right>
        </BorderPane>
    </top>
    <bottom>
        <BorderPane>
            <left>
                <Rectangle style="-fx-fill: black;" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150"/>
            </left>
            <right>
                <Rectangle style="-fx-fill: black;" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150"/>
            </right>
        </BorderPane>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

And the code would just be:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class CornersAndCenterController
extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    throws IOException {
        Region cornersAndCenter = FXMLLoader.load(
            CornersAndCenterController.class.getResource(
                "CornersAndCenterDemo.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(cornersAndCenter, 800, 800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Corners and Center");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(CornersAndCenterController.class, args);
    }
}
```